# Why doesn't the parameter index work?

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

In the documentation, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/

it uses {0} to reference the parameter 'movieTitle'.

```
@Query("MATCH (movie:Movie {title={0}}) RETURN movie")
Movie getMovieFromTitle(String movieTitle);
```

However, in my own code, if I use "{title={0}", my IntelliJ always reports a syntax error. I can resolve the issue by changing it to

```
{title:{movieTitle}
```

Here I have to use the actual argument name and the colon plus {}.

Is there any trick for this? I don't think the documentation is wrong.

Question 2:

If I want the node label "Movie" to be a parameter, it also shows an error message:

```
@Query("MATCH (movie:{label} {title={0}}) RETURN movie")
Movie getMovieFromTitle(String movieTitle, String label);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what version of IntelliJ you are using but the first query is right. There is also a test case for this in the [spring-data-neo4j project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/b2706ccad43f433455510dda7c3c1b25f36a82e7/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/examples/movies/repo/UserRepository.java#L66).

It is not possible to use the second query syntax because there is no support for this on the database level where the query gets executed. If it would be supported in SDN before making the call to the DB the query has to be parsed (and the pattern replaced) every time when the query get executed and SDN will loose the possibility to parse the query once and then just add the parameter values in subsequent calls. This will lower the performance of executing annotated query functions.

Comment: Thanks meistermeier. The links give good examples. For the second question, so basically I should not expect that to happen any time soon. Right?

Comment: Right, because this is not only a feature but also a behaviour change to the allowed server-side evaluated cypher syntax.